# How to change the date pattern for the sprints in the azure Devops project

Tags: azure-devops

How to change the date pattern for the devops project sprints?

currently we have month/date/year.

We need the following format pattern date/month/year

Is there any steps to configure the date pattern in the devops project?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To change Time and Locale settings, click the "User settings" button on the top right (it has the "user-with-cog" icon), select "Time and Locale" and set the "Date Pattern" accordingly.

###### Opening the user settings menu

[image: Opening User settings]

###### The user settings page

[image: User settings]

This should change how dates are displayed for the currently logged in user.

Comment: Thanks Rick for your quick reply.

Comment: I have already gone through those steps which you have suggested.

But the problems we are facing is on the sprints "due date"